# iterated logarithm equation misunderstanding

Tags: logarithms

I am trying to understand iterated logarithms. How anybody explain why $lg^{*}n = lg^{*}(lg\ n)$? What law can I apply to prove this equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_logarithm), you should have $$\log^*(x) = \log^*(\log x) + 1$$ for $x > 1$

Comment: Maybe you can also explain why $lg(lg^{*}n) < lg^{*}n$?

Comment: @Bob, for all $x>0$, $lg(x) < x$